# coldfusion - receiving posted JSON data and parsing it

Tags: json, coldfusion, cfc

This is the first time I'm writing a cfc that will catch JSON data from an external web server that would be posting information.

I'm working with a new service that can be set to send us, via HTTP POST to a URL I specify, a JSON packet of information regarding failed transactions.

I figured I'd setup a CFC with remote access to capture and deserialize the JSON data into something we could then act on.  However, I can't figure out how to setup the function in the CFC to received the data?

I set the URL to www.mydomain.com/com/processRemote.cfc?method=catchJSONdata&ReturnFormat=json

To test it, I setup a simple test page that should post session data:

```
<cfhttp 
  result="result"
  method="post" 
  url="http://www.mydomain.com/com/processRemote.cfc?method=catchJSONdata&ReturnFormat=json">

    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="content-type" value="application/json"/>
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#serializeJSON(session)#"/>
```

So where I'm lost is what's the cfargument name that I'd have in my cfc that I would initially store the JSON data in?  I have no control over the remote service that would be sending the JSON data.

Thanks,

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're reading content from the HTTP request body you wont find it in arguments scope - you'll need to extract it directly from the request:

```
if (cgi.content_type EQ "application/json")
{
    myData = deserializeJSON(ToString(getHTTPRequestData().content));
}
```

I use the Taffy[1] framework for building services like this (Disclaimer: I actually helped write the part of the framework that handles this case).

[1] http://atuttle.github.com/Taffy/

Comment: Thanks bpanulla!  I was trying to create a cfc that would accept the posted data directly.  Using your answer I created a cfm page that accepts the data, makes sure it's what we're expecting, and then hands it off to a cfc for processing.

Comment: That same technique should work just as well within your CFC method. Your CFC doesn't need to define any arguments (CFARGUMENT or script).

Comment: This had been bugging the hell out of me for hours... If I'm receiving a post, I'd expect the data in the Form scope! Apparently not if it's JSON posted in the body. 
Ahh well, lesson learned. Cheers.